# Can't refresh a table where data comes from mysql and displayed through php code

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

So the data in database comes every minute and i have no problem getting the data in the html table but i can't seem to make the table refresh. My temporary solution right now is to refresh the whole page every 5 seconds which isn't good enough because everytime i type in the input field the value disappears. I probably went through every solution on stackoverflow but i can't make any of them work. I even tried with the datatable of jquery but it didn't work either. Please help me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is my working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<style>
.student_label{
color:black;
font-size: 28px;
FONT-WEIGHT: 640;
}
</style>
</head>




<body">
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row">

<div class = "col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-6">
<label class = "student_label">student:</label>
</div>

<div class = "col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-6">

<input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Filter . .">

</div>
</div>

<div class="row mt-1">
<div class = "col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-12">
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "schooldata";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$List = ["class1.table, class2.table"];

echo '<table id="maintable" class= "table table-sm table-bordered table-hover"><thead class = "thead-dark"><tr><th>Ticker</th><th>Ema Crossover</th><th>RSI Value</th></tr></thead>';

foreach($List as $value){
$append = "_students";
$sql = "SELECT *  FROM `".$value.$append."` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tbody id='myTable'><tr><td>" .  $row["id"]. "</td><td> " .  $row["student"]. "</td><td> " .  $row["class"]. "</tbody></td></tr>";
    }

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

}


echo '</table>';

$conn->close();
?>
</div>
</div>



</div>
<script>

setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.reload(1);
}, 5000);


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable, #main").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});




</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing has to do with the approach you're taking. I'm going to discuss the general solution to the problem, just to point you in the right direction.

Consider what your code above does:

When a request comes in to your web server for `example.com/index.php` (or whatever you're calling it), the web server fires up the PHP interpreter, which goes through the code and prepares a full HTML page. The web server then passes that page back to the client.

It's important that you understand how the web server and PHP interpreter work together. What you have designed is a web page - that's all it is and that's all it ever will be. If you want to automatically update **part** of a web page, you need to do something different, like the following:

1. the client requests a web page like 'example.com/index.php'
2. the web server executes the code in `index.php` and sends an HTML page back to the client
3. now the user wants to update part of the page. Javascript code running on the client makes a request **to a different URL that's set up to send back only the part the client wants**
4. the web server executes different code that sends back **only the data for the part of the page that needs updating**
5. Javascript on the client receives this updated data and changes the existing page to show the new data.

The key here is that you need (at least) two routes - one to send the page and one to send updates (because you don't want to request the whole page again - that's what you're doing when you reload the page).

That's how it's done, in general terms.

Comment: thanks a lot. So i did make two pages one with the php code and the other one with a html code and made a div which loads the php file and wrote a jquery code to refresh that div. Now every time the new value arrives in the database, it gets rendered in the webpage

Answer (score 0):

You do need to use Javascript for this to work. There is no way you will make this work with only PHP as PHP is server-side rendered. Once the Page arrived in your browser there is no server to re-render the page.

You will have to

- Create an API-Endpoint that returns the database-content as JSON using PHP
- Use Javascript .fetch to connect to that new endpoint and get the data from there
- Make Javascript update the table accordingly
- Recall the Javascript method every 5 seconds

To give you a feeling here is a quick, not really pseudo-code "preview" of how to achieve it.

api.php

```php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// add some try catch around this
$pdo = Create DB Connection
$data = $pdo fetch data
http_response_code(200);
echo json_encode($data);
```

render.js

```js
cont reload = function() {
 fetch('/api') // get the data from API
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json(); // decode json
  })
  .then((data) => {
     // Find out whats new in (data) - or completely re-render the table using Javascript
    [CODE]
    setTimeout(reload, 5000); // then, after 5 seconds, reload again
  });
}

reload();
```

Comment: So i tried with getting the data as json route but i found a simpler solution by making two different files of php and html and writing a jquery to refresh a div in the html file. But thanks a lot for the input.